# Java MySQL bulk insert vs normal

Tags: java, mysql, insert, bulk

I tried to make the insert to mysql faster, so I werote a code with bulk insert. The problem is that when I run the following code, **results are the same** (Time elapsed: 2min, or 173sec) for both methods. Any comment on the matter is welcome.

```
MySQLConn mysqlconn = new MySQLConn(db,username,pass);
    Connection conn =mysqlconn.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    String query = "insert into table (column) values (?)";

    System.out.println("bulk insert started with "+10000 );
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i =0; i<10000;i++){

            ps.setString(1, "Name"+i);

            ps.addBatch();

            if(i%1000 == 0) ps.executeBatch();
        }
        ps.executeBatch();

        System.out.println("Time Taken="+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("End inserting data...");

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = (stopTime - startTime); 

    long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(elapsedTime);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsedTime);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime);


    System.out.println("Time elapsed: "+minutes+"min, or "+seconds+"sec");



    System.out.println("normal insert started with "+10000 );

    long startTimeNormal = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){ 
        String ins="Data"+i;
        Insert insert = new Insert(conn,ins,"db.table", "column" );
    }
    System.out.println("End inserting data...");

    long stopTimeNormal = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTimeNormal = (stopTimeNormal - startTimeNormal); 

    long daysN = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(elapsedTime);
    long hoursN = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsedTime);
    long minutesN = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime);
    long secondsN = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime);


    System.out.println("Time elapsed: "+minutesN+"min, or "+secondsN+"sec");
```

Comment: 2 minutes and 173 seconds are not "EXACTLY THE SAME".

Comment: in both cases the time was 2 minutes OR 173 seconds (2 minutes is the long minutesN = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `addBatch` and `executeBatch`, which is good, but you also need to set autocommit on your connection to false in order to achieve faster execution times.

Something along the lines:

```
Connection conn = mysqlconn.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false); // here

PreparedStatement ps = null;

String query = "insert into table (column) values (?)";

System.out.println("bulk insert started with "+10000 );
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

try {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i =0; i<10000;i++){

        ps.setString(1, "Name"+i);

        ps.addBatch();

        if(i%1000 == 0) {
            ps.executeBatch();
            conn.commit(); // here
        }
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    conn.commit(); // here

    System.out.println("Time Taken="+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOAOOOOU YEEESSS. It takes 1 second !!!! YES, 1 second for 10.000 inserts.... THANKSSS

Answer (score 1):

You need to set autocommit to `false`

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

And execute a commit manually after each `executeBath()`

[example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)